# multiple folder redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have been trying variations of the following without success:

```
Redirect permanent /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.?).html http://example.com/($3)
```

It seems to have no effect. I have also tried rewrite with similar lack of results.

I want all links similar to: http://example.com/2002/10/some-long-title.html
to redirect the browser and spiders to: http://example.com/some-long-title

When I save this to my server, and visit a link with the nested folders, it just returns a 404 with the original URL unchanged in the address bar. What I want is the new location in the address bar (and the content of course).

Comment: Where did you get that syntax from? It is invalid. I suggest you read the excellent documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I don't mess with apache or regex too often. I (apparently) mis-understood stuff from here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Hm, that guide looks fine to me. No idea where you got the 'Redirect permanent' from... Anyway, I added an answer, hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more or less what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
ReriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.?)\.html$ http://example.com/$3 [L,R=301]
```

This can be used inside the central apache configuration. If you have to use .htaccess files because you don't have access to the apache configuration then the syntax is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_alias, you want the `RedirectMatch`, not the regular `Redirect` directive:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/$3
```

Your last grouping needs to be `(.+)` which means *anything that's 1 character or more*, what you had before, `(.?)` matches *anything that is either 0 or 1 character*. Also, the last backreference doesn't need the parentheses.

Using mod_rewrite, it looks similar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/$3 [L,R=301]
```